# Hibernate JAVA | How to get an instance of EntityManager WITHOUT creating a new table?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

every time that I want to get the instance of Entity Manager is creating new tables in the database, so how I can get the EntityManager (to insert, delete, update the database) in Postgresql without creating new tables?

Entity "Medico":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medico")
@SequenceGenerator (name = "medico_seq",sequenceName="medico_seq",allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Medico implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "medico_seq")
    private Integer id = null;
    private String especializacao;
    private Integer diasRetorno;
    private Time tempoConsulta;    
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    private String telefone;
    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private String cep;
    private String endereco;
    private String bairro;
    private Integer enderecoNumero;


    public Medico(String especializacao, Integer diasRetorno, Time tempoConsulta, String nome, String cpf, String email, String senha, String telefone, String cidade, String estado, String cep, String endereco, String bairro, Integer enderecoNumero) {
        //...
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

"MedicoDAO"

```
package dao;

import entidade.Medico;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class MedicoDAO {

    public Medico salvar (Medico medico){

        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenciaPU").createEntityManager();
        try{em.getTransaction().begin();
            if(medico.getId()==null){
                em.persist(medico); //Faz o insert
            }
            else{
                medico = em.merge(medico); // Faz o update
            }

            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRO123: "+ex.getMessage());
        }finally{
            em.close();
        }
        em.close();
        return medico;

    }
}
```

"Persistence.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PersistenciaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entidade.HorarioAtendimentoMedico</class>
    <class>entidade.Medico</class>
    <class>entidade.Paciente</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/clinica"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

main:

```
package persistencia;

import dao.Auxiliar;
import dao.MedicoDAO;
import entidade.Medico;
import java.sql.Time;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Persistencia {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time t = new Time(2,3,4);
        Medico medico = new Medico("Cirurgiao",7,t,"Roberto","555.458.912-12","roberto@medico.com","12345","48 3275 0463", "Florianópolis", "SC", "88.222-200","Rua Bonita","Lagoa",12);

        MedicoDAO dao = new MedicoDAO();
        dao.salvar(medico);
    }    
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [create table medico]
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "medico" already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the Image. but try to change

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> // create new schema
```

to this:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> // update the schema
```

Comment: hi, I remove the image and put the xml code, can you see again, please? I tried to do what you said:


    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unexpected error parsing [file:/C:/Users/DigaoParceiro/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Persistencia/build/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml]

Answer (score 1):

I got!
What was needed is delete this line of the persistence.xml:

> property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/

Thanks for help me to notice this line

Comment: I see, i thought you are using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create/update a database schema upon startup of the project. javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action only has create,drop-and-create,drop values. it doesn't have update value thats why you got it wrong in the first place. but you solve it on your own. thanks by the way. for better understanding. read this. it will help.